Homebrew MySQL giving Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
When I try to run brew services start mysql, I'm getting the error:
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Someone told me that mysql may have been updated on my Mac (I'm on mysql 9.0.1, Sonoma 14.6.1, M1 MacBook Pro) and the databases need to be upgraded. But I can't figure out how to do that.
Is there a command I need to run to upgrade my databases after a mysql update?
I tried stopping, starting and restarting mysql. I also tried deleting the symlink and relinking.

Run brew info mysql, in the caveat part, there's a detailed migration instructions.
❯ brew info mysql
...
==> Caveats
Upgrading from MySQL <8.4 to MySQL >9.0 requires running MySQL 8.4 first:
 - brew services stop mysql
 - brew install mysql@8.4
 - brew services start mysql@8.4
 - brew services stop mysql@8.4
 - brew services start mysql

We've installed your MySQL database without a root password. To secure it run:
    mysql_secure_installation

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To connect run:
    mysql -u root

To start mysql now and restart at login:
  brew services start mysql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir\=/usr/local/var/mysql


After this migration, if mysql still fails to start, check the *.err log file in $(brew --prefix)/var/mysql folder.
